# Having syntax issue for Spring Mongo @Query while trying to validate null values coming from the front end

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to recieve data from the front end and then passing it to my @Query annotation, if the value is null , it would skip it , else it would look for it inside the Mongo database.

So far I have tried this `@Query`

```
 @Query("{$and: [{"
            + "            $or: [{"
            + "                $where: '?0 == null'"
            + "            }, {"
            + "                name: '?0'"
            + "            }]"
            + "        }, {"
            + "            $or: [{"
            + "                $where: '?1 == null'"
            + "            }, {"
            + "                batch: '?1'"
            + "            }]"
            + "        }, {"
            + "            $or: [{"
            + "                $where: '?2 == null'"
 `          + "            }, {"
            + "                city: '?2'"
            + "            }]"
            + "        }]}")
```

Now for the above query i am getting the following syntax issue

`SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal on server`

Now i know the issue is how i am writing the `$where` part, but I am not really able to understand it.

Thanks.